# Lotus Notes Application reverting to default views when clicking outline entries

Tags: lotus-notes

I created an outline embedded in a page that is used in the main frameset used within a notes application.  When I click on any of the outline entries, the window reverts back to display all available views in the application.  I'd like it to maintain just the outline on the left and not show all available views.  There must be a way to do this as I've seen it in other applications, but I'm not sure how.

Is there a setting or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you given the frame, where you display the view the name 'NotesView'?
Have you set the outline entry a target frame or a default target frame in the outline?
Developer Questions are better placed in StackOverflow ...

Comment: That was the key.  My Outline Entry Frame Target didn't match my display frame name.  Thank you umeli.